# Facebook Deeplink not taking to iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, facebook, swift3

I have integrated required Facebook pods and completed all steps as mentioned in the Facebook guide for Ads Deep linking

ANd write Below code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
    Settings.isAutoInitEnabled = true
    ApplicationDelegate.initializeSDK(nil)
    AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Received error while fetching deferred app link %@", error)
        }
        if let url = url {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using format for deeplink : **example://category=Proctology**

However, when I send the test deeplink from FB Ads console, clicking on the Ads opens the app page on AppStore instead of opening my app.
Please help

Comment: Any luck with this one? I am experiencing the same thing here.

Comment: If you still have this question, you should update it with samples of the "steps as mentioned": there's likely an error in (part of) your configuration.